# Derive the following rule of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

This rule is sometimes called resolution:

(p ∨ q) ∧ (~p ∨ r) ⇒ (q ∨ r)

How can it be derived with boolean algebra?

Comment: You can check that when the LHS evaluates to $1$ also the RHS does.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza I would prefer an algebraic solution rather than brute force

Comment: You cannot "simplify the LHS to $(q ∨ r)$" because RHS and LHS are **not** equivalent. The inference rules "works" before the LHS *implies* the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using boolean algebra you rewrite one expression as a different, but $equivalent$ expression. So, using algebra you don't end up with a statement that is merely *implied*.  So, you typically don't use algebra to demonstrate some implication.

One thing we can do, however, is to derive a conjunction, one conjunct of which is the implied statement. If we can do that, then obviously the implied statement is indeed a logical consequence. So, let's try that:

$(p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Distribution)

$(p \land \neg p) \lor (p \land r) \lor (q \land \neg p) \lor (q \land r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Complement)

$\bot \lor (p \land r) \lor (q \land \neg p) \lor (q \land r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Identity)

$(p \land r) \lor (q \land \neg p) \lor (q \land r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Distribution)

$[(p \lor q) \land (p \lor \neg p) \land (r \lor q) \land (r \lor \neg p)] \lor (q \land r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Complement)

$[(p \lor q) \land \top \land (r \lor q) \land (r \lor \neg p)] \lor (q \land r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Identity)

$[(p \lor q) \land (r \lor q) \land (r \lor \neg p)] \lor (q \land r) \Leftrightarrow$ (Distribution)

$[p \lor q \lor (q \land r)] \land [r \lor q \lor (q \land r)] \land [r \lor \neg p \lor (q \land r)] \Leftrightarrow$ (Absorption)

$(p \lor q) \land (r \lor q) \land (r \lor \neg p) \Leftrightarrow$ (Commutation)

$(q \lor r) \land (p \lor q) \land (r \lor \neg p)$

So, this statement is equivalent to the original statement, and since $q \lor r$ is one of the conjuncts of this conjunction, it is clearly implied by this statement, and hence by the original statement as well.

Comment: Nicely done. However, I'm confused why you say that "you typically don't use algebra to demonstrate some implication" when that is what you just did in your proof.

Comment: Well, I said 'typically'', because most of the times you use it for showing equivalences. As I demonstrated, it can be used for implication, but as you can see, it can be a bit of effort, and there are better methods for demonstrating implication, such as formal proofs, truth trees, and others. In fact, in this case even a full truth table would have been more efficient!